# Como sacar promedio de SJF

Tags: c++, array

Hola estoy haciendo un programa en C++ donde tengo que programar un "Program for Shortest Job First (SJF)"
Lo que no se hace es al momento de sacar el promedio de un conjunto de arreglos pero cuando ya estén ordenados de menor a mayor. Es difícil de explicar pero me explicare mejor, el usuario tiene que digitar un numero "x" de números que serán guardados en un arraylist y esos se ordenaran de menor a mayor, ya que estos están ordenados de menor a mayor, tengo que sacar la suma y el promedio de esos números ya ordenados de menor a mayor, pero la suma tiene que ser de esta forma.

"Numeros digitados por el usuario"
-> " 10,9,3,6,7 ".

"Numeros ya ordenados de menor a mayor" -> "3 -> 6 -> 7 -> 9 -> 10".

"Sacar el promedio de los números ya ordenados pero que el resultado de la suma anterior sea un nuevo numero" ->

3+6 = 9

9+7 = 16

16+9 = 25

25+10 = 35

(3+9+16+25+35) / 5 = 17.6

---Output---

```
----Simulacion de SJF----

¿Cuantos procesos desea?: 5
Tiempo de proceso [A]: 10
Tiempo de proceso [B]: 9
Tiempo de proceso [C]: 3
Tiempo de proceso [D]: 6
Tiempo de proceso [E]: 7

3 --> 6 --> 7 --> 9 --> 10 --> NULL
El promedio es: 7
```

-----Mi código------

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[27];
    char procesos [] = {'A','B','C','D','E'};
    int i,j,n,aux;
    float promedio=0,total;

      cout<<"----Simulacion de SJF----\n"<<endl;
      cout<<"¿Cuantos procesos desea?: ";
      cin>>n;
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        
        cout<<"Tiempo de proceso ["<<procesos[i]<<"]: ";
        cin>>arr[i];
        
        total=total+arr[i];
        promedio=total/n; 
    }

      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){    
          if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){ 

            aux = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = aux;
          }
        }
      }
      cout<<"\n";
      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" --> ";
      }
      if(i==n){  
        cout<<"NULL";
      }

      cout<<"\nEl promedio es: "<<promedio<<"\n\n";
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes declarar un arreglo auxiliar donde mismo declaras el **arreglo arr:**

```
int arr[27];
int auxArr[27];
```

Luego vendría la parte donde llenas el arreglo que solo se ocuparía de esto por lo que el cálculo del promedio ya saldría de ahí.

Y ahora viene la parte nueva que es la que calcularía el promedio según tu explicación:

```
auxArr[0] = arr[0];
int sum = arr[0];

for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    sum += arr[i];
    auxArr[i] = sum;
}
```

Y ahora vendría el cálculo del promedio de los números guardados en **auxArr**:

```
int total = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    total += auxArr[i];
}

float promedio = total / n;
```

Él promedio se calcula fuera del ciclo para que se calcule una vez, de lo contrario cada vez que corra el ciclo se ejecutará n veces.

Este algoritmo lo que hace es guardar en un arreglo auxiliar las sumas de los elementos del array original y sobre los elementos de este arreglo auxiliar es que se calcula el promedio que pides.

Answer (score 4):

Salvo que tengas que guardar los cálculos intermedios para usarlos en alguna parte, lo que pides es tan sencillo como usar una variable auxiliar para ir almacenando el resultado de la suma anterior:

```
#include <iostream>

int calcularSuma( int *values, int count ) {
  int curr = values[0];
  int acu = 0;

  for( int idx = 1; idx < count; ++idx ) {
    curr += values[idx];
    acu += curr;
  }

  return acu;
}

int main( ) {
  int data[] = { 3, 6, 7, 9, 10 };

  std::cout << "total = " << calcularSuma( data, sizeof( data ) / sizeof( data[0] ) ) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```